# Integrating $\arcsin \left(\frac{1}{2r} \left(\left(\lambda^2+(r+t)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}-\left(\lambda^2+(r-t)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

In a mathematical physical problem, one has to deal with a non-trivial finite integral given by
$$  
f(r,R,\lambda) = \int_0^R \arcsin \left( \frac{1}{2r} 
\left( \left( \lambda^2+(r+t)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} 
-\left( \lambda^2+(r-t)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\right) \right) \, \mathrm{d}t \, ,
$$ 
where $0<r<R$ and $\lambda>0$ are parameters.

In particular, for $\lambda=0$, it can easily be shown that
$$
f(r,R,0) = \int_0^r \arcsin \left( \frac{t}{r} \right) \, \mathrm{d}t
+ \frac{\pi}{2} \int_r^R \mathrm{d} t
= -r+\frac{\pi R}{2} \, .
$$

Is there a way to deal with the above integral for arbitrary values of the parameter $\lambda$?
Your suggestions and inputs are most welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define
$$ g \colon [0,\infty)^3 \to [0,1] \, , \, g(r,t,\lambda) = \begin{cases} \frac{\sqrt{\lambda^2 + (r+t)^2} - \sqrt{\lambda^2 + (r-t)^2}}{2 r} &, \, r > 0 \\ \frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda^2 + t^2}} &, \, r = 0 \, \wedge \, \lambda > 0 \\ 1 & , \, r = 0 \, \wedge \, \lambda = 0\end{cases} \, ,$$
and $A = \{(x,y,z) \in [0,\infty)^3 : x \leq y\}$. Then $g$ is continuous on $[0,\infty) \setminus (0,0,0)$ and bounded ($0 \leq g \leq 1$ follows from the mean value theorem). Therefore,
$$ f \colon A \to [0,\infty) \, , \, f(r,R,\lambda) = \int \limits_0^R \arcsin(g(r,t,\lambda)) \, \mathrm{d} t \, ,$$
is well-defined and satisfies $0 \leq f(r,R,\lambda) \leq \frac{\pi}{2} R$ for $(r,R,\lambda) \in A$. The substitution $t = R s$ shows that $f(r,R,\lambda) = R f\left(\frac{r}{R},1,\frac{\lambda}{R}\right) $ holds for $(r,R,\lambda) \in A$, so it is sufficient to compute
$$ F \colon [0,1] \times [0,\infty) \to \left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right] \, , \, F(r,\lambda) = f(r,1,\lambda) = \int \limits_0^1 \arcsin(g(r,t,\lambda)) \, \mathrm{d} t \, .$$

---

You have already derived $F(r,0) = \frac{\pi}{2} - r$ for $r \in [0,1]$, so we will assume $\lambda > 0$ from now on. Integration by parts yields
\begin{align} 
F(0,\lambda) &= \int \limits_0^1 \arcsin \left(\frac{t}{\lambda^2 + t^2}\right) \, \mathrm{d} t = \arcsin \left(\frac{1}{1 + \lambda^2}\right) - \int \limits_0^1 \frac{\lambda t}{\lambda^2 + t^2} \, \mathrm{d} t \\
&= \arcsin \left(\frac{1}{1 + \lambda^2}\right) - \frac{\lambda}{2} \log\left(1+\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\right) \, .
\end{align}
Now let $r \in (0,1]$. It is easy to see that $g$ is differentiable and strictly increasing with respect to the second variable, so we can integrate by parts again and let $u = g(r,t,\lambda)$ to obtain
\begin{align}
F(r,\lambda) &= \arcsin(g(r,1,\lambda)) - \int \limits_0^1 \frac{t}{\sqrt{1 - g(r,t,\lambda)^2}} \, \partial_2 g(r,t,\lambda) \, \mathrm{d} t \\
&= \arcsin(g(r,1,\lambda)) - \int \limits_0^{g(r,1,\lambda)} \frac{g(r,\cdot,\lambda)^{-1} (u)}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}}  \, \mathrm{d} u \, .
\end{align}
Solving $u = g(r,t,\lambda)$ for $t$ is straightforward and we find (letting $\sqrt{\lambda^2 + r^2(1-u^2)} = \lambda v$)
\begin{align}
F(r,\lambda) &= \arcsin(g(r,1,\lambda)) - \int \limits_0^{g(r,1,\lambda)} \frac{u \sqrt{\lambda^2 + r^2(1-u^2)}}{1 - u^2}  \, \mathrm{d} u \\
&= \arcsin(g(r,1,\lambda)) - \lambda \int \limits_{\sqrt{1+\frac{r^2}{\lambda^2}(1-g(r,1,\lambda)^2)}}^{\sqrt{1 + \frac{r^2}{\lambda^2}}} \frac{v^2}{v^2-1}  \, \mathrm{d} v \\
&= \arcsin(g(r,1,\lambda)) - \left[\sqrt{\lambda^2 + r^2} - \sqrt{\lambda^2 + r^2(1-g(r,1,\lambda)^2)}\right] \\
&\phantom{= ~} - \lambda \left[\operatorname{arcoth} \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{r^2}{\lambda^2}(1-g(r,1,\lambda)^2)}\right) - \operatorname{arcoth} \left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{r^2}{\lambda^2}}\right)\right] \, .
\end{align}

---

The final result for $0 < r < R$ and $\lambda > 0$ is
\begin{align}
f(r,R,\lambda) &= R \arcsin(g(r,R,\lambda)) - \left[\sqrt{\lambda^2 + r^2} - \sqrt{\lambda^2 + r^2(1-g(r,R,\lambda)^2)}\right] \\
&\phantom{= ~} - \lambda \left[\operatorname{arcoth} \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{r^2}{\lambda^2}(1-g(r,R,\lambda)^2)}\right) - \operatorname{arcoth} \left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{r^2}{\lambda^2}}\right)\right] \, .
\end{align}
It contains the edge cases $r = 0$ and $\lambda = 0$ as limits. Although it looks quite complicated, expansions like
$$ f(r,R,\lambda) \stackrel{\lambda \to \infty}{\sim} \frac{R^2}{2 \lambda} \left[1 - \frac{R^2 + 3 r^2}{6 \lambda^2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{R^4}{\lambda^4}\right)\right] $$
are easily obtainable from CAS.

Comment: +1, nice. What encouraged you to actually invert $g(r,\cdot,\lambda)$ explicitly? The algebraic form intimidated me from trying. It surprises me that it turns out to have a nice low order form. Was it the symmetry, perhaps associated with $\pm t$ in $g(r,t,\lambda)$, that gave you hope that the inversion might be simple enough to work?

Comment: @Hans Yes, it was indeed the symmetry of the two square roots that made this method seem feasible. The equation must be squared twice to get rid of the roots, potentially leading to terms up to the fourth order in $t$. However, almost all of them cancel due to symmetry, leaving only a simple quadratic term.

Comment: Yes, the cancellation is the miracle. What I want to ask is whether you saw the telltale of this cancellation from the beginning which encouraged you to plow ahead and try it or you just boldly tried it no matter what?

Comment: @Hans I saw that the higher order terms would cancel and decided to give it a try, but the cancellation of the linear terms was a pleasant surprise.